# Redirect specific folder to HTTPS and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, ssl

I know this question was asked so many times on SO, and I found all the relevant answers to my post, but my situation is a bit more unique, therefore I couldn't use the given answers as solution for my problem.

I have a website http://www.example.com which has a folder with the name: secure.
When a user tries to go to http://www.example.com/secure, he should be redirected to the HTTPS version of the site.
Now for the tricky part -
on the secure page there is only HTTPS links, as requested by every SSL certificate. specifically there is a link to https://www.example.com - but when a user clicks it, he should be redirected to the HTTP version of the site. as mentioned - the main page is not secure.

I figured I would need two Rewrite rules:

1. Redirecting everyone trying to get to http://www.example.com/secure to HTTPS protocol.
2. Redirecting everyone trying to get to https://www.example.com to HTTP protocol.

This is what i have now in .htaccess in the root directory of the domain based on another question I found here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Turn SSL on for /secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/secure
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but /secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secure
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine for redirecting the secure page to HTTPS, but I can't figure out why it's not redirecting https://www.example.com to HTTP.

Also worth mentioning, I have the following code in the same .htaccess that I can't remove.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Try your rules based on `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI`.  `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and **it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules**, unlike `REQUEST_URI` variable.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Turn SSL on for /secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /secure [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Turn SSL off everything but /secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/secure [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Also better to test this in a new browser after clearing browser cache.

Comment: This seems to work with the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on the secure page, but on every other page when you try to enter with HTTPS, the HTTPS remains.. you can check live example at http://meretz.org.il and the secure page is https://meretz.org.il/donations

Comment: Do you have other rules also is the the only code? Does `donations` also have a .htaccess file?

Comment: the donations folder does not contain any file at all for the moment. I edited my question with the code I already have in the .htaccess, does it interfere with the code you provided?

Comment: Don't forget to change `secure` with `donations` in the rule. And you should have mentioned presence of WP. I'm not WP expert but I think you need to change site and home URL also in permalink. Make sure WP rules are below these 2 rules. I need to rush for some work, will check this thread in couple of hours.

Comment: Yeah, I changed secure to donations. Your'e right, I'll mention it's wordpress and I'll try what you said. Thank you mate.